# Python Ping-Pong game, the ball speed randomly changes during paddle movement

Tags: python, game-physics, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, pong

I started off with learning python and tried following  tutorial on how to make a pong game in python. The speed of the ball in my game fluctuates somehow and is not consistent, especially when I'm moving either of the paddles using W or S and the arrow keys, the speed changes and causes inconvenience. I've checked the code many times for bugs but I'm unable to figure it out. Here's my code.

```
import turtle

win = turtle.Screen()
win.title("Pong by killkennyale")
win.bgcolor("black")
win.setup(width=800, height=600)
win.tracer(0)

# Score
score_a = 0
score_b = 0


# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0) #speed of animation of paddle
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1) 
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.penup() #turtle draws lines, we don't want that duh
paddle_a.goto(-350,0) #coordinates for turtle-paddle


# Paddle B
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b.speed(0) #speed of animation of paddle
paddle_b.shape("square")
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1) 
paddle_b.color("white")
paddle_b.penup() #turtle draws lines, we don't want that duh
paddle_b.goto(350,0) #coordinates for turtle-paddle


# Ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0) #speed of animation of ball
ball.shape("circle")
ball.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1) 
ball.color("white")
ball.penup() #turtle draws lines, we don't want that duh
ball.goto(0,0) #coordinates for turtle-ball
ball.dx = 0.5 #speed of x
ball.dy = 0.5 #speed of y

# Pen
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle() # we don't need to see it
pen.goto(0, 260)
pen.write("Player A: {} Player B: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 16, "normal"))

# now we gotta make the paddle move using a keyboard

# Function
def paddle_a_up():
    y = paddle_a.ycor() #assign y-coordinate to variable y
    y = y + 20 #add 20 pixels to y-coordinate
    paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_a_down():
    y = paddle_a.ycor() #assign y-coordinate to variable y
    y = y - 20 #add 20 pixels to y-coordinate
    paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_b_up():
    y = paddle_b.ycor() #assign y-coordinate to variable y
    y = y + 20 #add 20 pixels to y-coordinate
    paddle_b.sety(y)

def paddle_b_down():
    y = paddle_b.ycor() #assign y-coordinate to variable y
    y = y - 20 #add 20 pixels to y-coordinate
    paddle_b.sety(y)

# Keyboard Binding
win.listen() # tells the turtle to listen to the keyboard
win.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")
win.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "s")
# when we press 'w'or's' then it calls paddle_a_up or down and adds or subtracts 20 to the y coordinate
win.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, "Up")
win.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, "Down")
# when we press 'up'or'down' arrow then it calls paddle_b_up or down and adds or subtracts 20 to the y coordinate


#Main Game Loop
while True:
    win.update()

    # Move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # Border Checking
    if ball.ycor() > 290:
        ball.sety(290) # it reaches roof at 300
        ball.dy = ball.dy * -1
   
    if ball.ycor() < -290:
        ball.sety(-290) # it reaches roof at 300
        ball.dy = ball.dy * -1
   
    if ball.xcor() > 390:
        ball.goto(0,0)
        ball.dx = ball.dx * -1
        score_a += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Player A: {} Player B: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 16, "normal"))

    if ball.xcor() < -390:
        ball.goto(0,0)
        ball.dx = ball.dx * -1
        score_b += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Player A: {} Player B: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 16, "normal"))

    # Paddle and ball collisions
    if (ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_b.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > paddle_b.ycor() - 40):
        ball.setx(340)
        ball.dx *= -1

    if (ball.xcor() < -340 and ball.xcor() > -350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_a.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > paddle_a.ycor() - 40):
        ball.setx(-340)
        ball.dx *= -1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix inconsistent frame rate (speed) in python turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55495581/how-to-fix-inconsistent-frame-rate-speed-in-python-turtle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a main/game/animation loop that is set up in a way that moves things forward at a **constant** speed, instead of at a variable speed as you have it currently.

With a `while` loop set up as in your example, the next iteration of the loop will be called immediately after the previous iteration, and each iteration can take a *variable* amount of time to complete. But your movement amount for the ball and paddles are *fixed*, and that's why you have a problem. For example, it might take 1ms for the first frame / iteration of the loop, but 7ms for the second frame / iteration because a key was pushed and more calculation is consequently done by the computer. So in frame 1 the ball would move `dx` and `dy` in just 1ms, but then in the next frame it takes the ball 7ms to move only `dx` and `dy` again — in other words, your ball/paddle movement is therefore variable, as it is happening at a variable number of frames per second instead of a fixed fps.

So you could tell the computer how often to constantly advance the game/animation, rather than have it advance at a variable speed. (Else, adjust things to that variable speed if you prefer). You could do that through a callback function that runs at a constant framerate — e.g. the `frame()` function in [Pong with Turtle Graphics: Part 2](https://wecode24.com/stories/abraham/pong-with-turtle-graphics-part-2):

```py
framerate_ms = 40  # Every how many milliseconds must frame function be called?

def frame () :
    screen.ontimer(frame, framerate_ms)  # schedule this function to be called again
    check_if_someone_scores()
    update_paddle_positions()
    update_ball_position()
    screen.update()                      # display the new frame

frame()                                  # call it manually the first time
```

Comment: I don't wanna set a variable speed as of now. I wanna set is constant and my code is causing it to change when I use the keyboard controls for some reasons. maybe you could try it out in your editor?

Comment: If my explanation isn't clear, there is a much more detailed explanation of the issue and ways to approach it, on [gameprogrammingpatterns.com](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html)