# Turtle graphics - framerate?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, frame-rate, python-turtle

Using Turtle Graphics and Python -- I have a group of 10 basic graphic elements on the screen at the same time and it runs sluggish.  As soon as some of the elements "leave" the graphic window, it speeds up considerably.  Is there a way to maintain the same frame-rate, regardless of the number of graphic elements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix inconsistent frame rate (speed) in python turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55495581/how-to-fix-inconsistent-frame-rate-speed-in-python-turtle)

Answer (score 1):

You should say:

```
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.tracer("I recommend you do 0") # Make sure you do this at the beginning.
```

By using `screen.tracer()` you can control the frame rate

Comment: Do I need to add in a time.sleep as well?

Comment: No, you don't have to add time.sleep() for more information you can check out this link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html And add the screen.tracer() at the beginning